# Is it expensive to alloc-init inside a for-loop in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, for-loop, initialization

Just a question I had regarding general programming.

I could go for either of the options:

```
for(some_conditions)
{
 NSFileManager * fm = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
 BOOL result = [fm moveItemAtPath:x toPath:y error:&err];
}
```

Or I could go for:

```
NSFileManager * fm = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
for(some_conditions)
{
 BOOL result = [fm moveItemAtPath:x toPath:y error:&err];
}
```

What I want to know is, are there any computational differences between the two with respect to time and space taken to execute the two options?
Thanks a bunch in advance :)

Comment: Because you are hitting the filesystem, the slight amount of additional time related to repeated alloc/free of the file manager will be irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't plan to use NSFileManagerDelegate, consider using the `defaultManager`:

```
NSFileManager *fm = NSFileManager.defaultManager;
```

Not only it is initialized once, but you can imagine that it might keep some internal in-memory caches to speed up certain operations.

If interested about performance you should add (and print) timings to your code and try it with real data. My guess is that here the time to `alloc/init` is negligible compared to the `moveItemAtPath`.

The space allocation can be checked in Xcode allocations instrument or debugging memory graph. My guess is that it is the same for both, because in the first variant `fm` is destroyed at the end of each loop iteration.